# Outer div element does not expand when inner div is expanding

Tags: css, html, expand, outer-join

I have a "content box"-div element into which i'm loading pages using php/include(). Now I made a "box"-div that is to be loaded into the "content box"-div, works fine, just when the content of the inner div is growing too large then just the inner div is expanding and "growing" out of the outer div.

I want the outer div element to grow if the inner div is exceeding the outer div's min-height.

I googled some and found (even on stackoverflow) that I have to use a div with style="clear: both" right after the div containers that are using 'float: right;' or 'float: left;'.

Though I'm not really sure where to put those, I played around a bit but still can't figure out how to get this working.

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle inner div exceeding outer div](http://jsfiddle.net/xMH7b/1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden` to your outer `div` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMH7b/2/)

```
div.contentbox_body {
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Does anyone know why clear: both didn't work in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position: absolute;` to your div.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/xMH7b/3/)*** is the modified fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i'll go with Zoltan's solution as I had bad experience regarding cross-browser-compatibility using 'position: absolute'.